# Show that $S$ is invertible if and only if whenever $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent, then $S(v_1),\dots,S(v_n)$ are also linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Show that $S \in \operatorname{Hom}(\textsf V , \textsf V)$ is invertible if and only if whenever $v_1,\dots,v_n \in \textsf V$ are linearly independent, then $S(v_1),\dots,S(v_n)$ are also linearly independent.

Here $S$ is invertible means that the constant term of the minimal polynomial for $S$ is not $0$.

I need help to prove that when $S(v_1),\dots,S(v_n)$ is linearly independent and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are also linearly independent then $S$ is invertible because I have proven that if $S$ is regular and $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent then $S(v_1),\dots,S(v_n)$ are also linearly independent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $n$? If $n=\dim V$, What is the matrix of $S$ w.r.t. the two bases given by the two systems? (Please fill in the needed details, since just writing a $V$ does not mean we know what it is, and also fix the latex input.)

Comment: Having $V$ as an $n$ dimensional vector space is going to be critical to the correctness of the statement.

Comment: I'm assuming your $V$ is a vector space. Any injective (or, one-to-one) linear transformation $V \rightarrow V$ will preserve independent sets.. However, it will not always  preserve a basis unless $V$ has finite dimension. Consequently, it will not necessarily be invertible. If $V$ has finite dimension $n,$ it should be relatively easy to show $S$ is invertible because it will take a basis to a basis.

Comment: Here n is any natural number such that n is less than or equal to dim V. V is finite dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $V$, then so is $\{S(v_i)\}$, by assumption.

Let $v = \sum a_i v_i \in V$ be an arbitrary vector, and write $v = \sum c_i S(v_i) = \sum S(c_iv_i)=S(\sum c_iv_i)$ by linearity. So, $S$ is onto.

Suppose $S(v)=S(w)$. Then write $v=\sum a_iv_i$ and $w=\sum b_iv_i$. We have: $S(\sum a_iv_i) = S(\sum b_iv_i)$ or

$$\sum (a_i-b_i)S(v_i) = 0$$

Since $S(v_i)$'s are linearly independent, $a_i=b_i$ for each $i$, i.e. $v=w$ so that $S$ is injective.